# History disappearing as a prop for child in my react app after using Redux's connect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am learning React and Redux and I am having a problem with my sample app. I am trying to wire up an app that will navigate to either the login page or the home page depending on whether it is already logged in.

App layer:

```
import Login from './../connectors/LoginConnector'
import Index from './../connectors/IndexConnector'
import Home from './../connectors/HomeConnector'

const App = props => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
export default App
```

Index view:

```
const Index = (props) => {

    if (props.loggedIn) {
        return(
            <Home/>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Login/>
        )
    }
}
export default Index
```

Index container component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("Index state = ", state)
    return {...state}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Index)
```

Login view:

```
const Login = (props) => {
    console.log("Login props = ", props)
    let user, pass
    const login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.login(user.value, pass.value)    
        props.history.push("/home");
    };
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={login}>
          <label> Username:
            <input type="text" className="form-control col-md-12" ref = {node => user = node}/>
          </label>
          <label> Password:
            <input type="password" className="form-control col-md-12" ref = {node => pass = node}/>
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
export default Login
```

Login container component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {...state}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: (user, pass) => dispatch(logIn(user, pass))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

The application was working before I added Index (when "/" routed directly to `Login`), but after adding Index I get [this error when I try to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnauG.png). It seems that, when using both React Router and Redux, the `history` part of `props` is being erased or somehow not passed to `Index`'s child component. If I print the `props` at the top of the `Index` view and then the `Login` view, I get `{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined, username: null, …}` and then `{username: null, password: null, loggedIn: false, login: ƒ}`. How do I prevent `Login` from losing important props such as `history`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access router objects( i.e history ) through props of the component, either the component has to be rendered via `Route` or it should wrap with withRouter higher-order component.

Since `Login` component is rendered with JSX inside the render method of another component, you should wrap it with [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component as follows before you export it.

`export default withRouter(Login);`

Comment: Thank you, this helped solve the problem and eliminated the error. However, I am still not getting expected behavior - that is, if I log in and then navigate to "/", it is sending me to login when it should be sending me to home (upon page reload state is being reverted back to initial state) - do you know why this might be?

Comment: Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist. The state will refresh on page reload, you'll need to use a middleware.

Comment: Or you can use `localStorage` , if you don't want a middleware.